How to add own iptables rule on host after run Nomad job?
I have the infrastructure with Nomad. For some jobs I need to add custom iptables rule (iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu) first on node host (not in a container - it's wery important!) and automate it. I added this rule to cron and reboot server. But when nomad job starting I see CNI firewall plugin rule on first position and my rule on second.
I wrote a script which check is my rule on the first position and if not add it. Its work fine but this is not solution IaC. Also jobs can migrated to others servers and rule no more needed.
Maybe you know some "nice" solution with Nomad? For example, when my nomad job is started do some check for the iptables rule. Also I tried to undestand how to create own rule with CNI firewall plugin but it's seems impossible.
What I'm expecting (on server 1, server 2 for example):

Server 1 and server 2 are clean, no custom rule, no CNI rule.
I run a nomad job which requires my custom rule. CNI firewall add own rules and after that I need to add my rule on first position in host rules.
If nomad job migrate to server 2, delete my rule on server 1 (it's not very important - I will use node pool to isolate this job. So job can't migrate to server 3 and create a rule which may harm others jobs. But I don't need 100+ the same rules on my hosts)
When job successfuly migrated to server 2 - check if my rule is present first do nothing or add my custom rule on first position to the host.

Sorry for wrong tags - nomad, iptables, cni are absent.
